# Introductory Digital logic/design question

Tags: digital-logic, computers, state-machines

How can I abstractly describe a sequence of instructions/function at a register transfer level, given a certain set of instructions.

For example, here is the type of questions that we would be asked for our homework.

(1)Implement the following program repeatedly using a single 8-bit
adder/subtracter (AS) module, 8-bit registers, as few as possible as small as possible
counters and combinational modules of your choice.
The AS module executes addition, when control signal c1 is 0 and subtraction when
control signal c1 is 1. Every five cycles the 7-bit input variables b, c, and e are updated
with new values. All values (given and calculated) are positive. Values a, f, g, h, and d
should be available one each clock cycle, in their respective order.

statement 1. a = b + c;

statement 2. f = b + e;

statement 3. g = a − c;

statement 4. h = b + e;

statement 5. d = b − c;

And a more challenging question. 
 Design a system that computes the following expression:
F = a*x<sup>4</sup>
 + b*x<sup>3</sup>
 + c*x<sup>2</sup>
 + d*x + e
The constant values a, b, c, d, and e are stored in five shift registers. Variable x arrives
every 8 clock cycles. Use the minimal number of shift registers, multipliers, and adders to
design the system.

Im not necessarily looking for answers to this, I just want to know if there is someone that can provide me with certain topics that would allow me to solve these types of problems. Essentially, I want to be guided in the right direction so that I may be able to understand this topic. 
I understand we have to use ALU's and registers, but how can I translate this to some sort of state table and diagram so that i may implement the situation.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

There are hadware description languages
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language

A very common one is VHDL
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL

But if you are starting with all this you should go to a Digital Systems textbook, normally they start with AHPL (A Hardware Programming Language). Here is a nice introduction to it: http://www.docfoc.com/a-hardware-programming-language